# Can't start Apache server with Xampp

Tags: apache, xampp

When im trying to start Apache it shows this??

```
Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
If you need more help, copy and post this
entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: Have you already tried following the advises, the error message is showing you?

Comment: There is no single answer to this kind of issue. You have to do some research locally. Have you looked at the `Windows Event Viewer` for messages from `Apache` if not, then do, then post what you find as an edit to your question

Answer (score 0):

Try to uncheck using ports 80 and 443 in Skype under Tools->Advanced->Connections.
Then exit Skype, end Skype process in Task manager, run again Skype.
Then restart Apache.
I have this problem with XAMPP and succesfully done it with these steps.

Kind regards